# Entity Framework Core Update using Generic Repository but only certain fields

Tags: c#, sql, performance, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Every single Generic Repository I see is just like this

```
    public async Task UpdateAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        this.dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);

        _ = await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Problem is if i have an entity with over 50 columns and I'm not sure if this is a good approach.

Here is a quick example of the sql generated by EF Core when updating vs Attach

```
    var reference = _context.References.Find(1);

        reference.Name= "123456";

       _context.References.Update(reference);

        _context.SaveChanges();


        _context.References.Attach(reference);
        _context.Entry(reference).Property(r => r.Name).IsModified = true;

        _context.SaveChanges();
```

here is sql for update command

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE [Production].[References] SET [IsDeleted] = @p0, [Name] = @p1
  WHERE [Id] = @p2;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

and attach

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE [Production].[References] SET [Name] = @p0
  WHERE [Id] = @p1;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Does it matter if i just update the wholy entity vs mark specific properties as modified? Since only the 1st approach works on a Generic Repository.

**UPDATE**

OK I found a way to deal with this. It seems the best way to update an entity as per

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/54169736/what-is-better-way-to-update-data-in-ef-core

is using

_context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

> SetValues will only mark as modified the properties that have
>   different values to those in the tracked entity. This means that when
>   the update is sent, only those columns that have actually changed will
>   be updated. (And if nothing has changed, then no update will be sent
>   at all.)

and the generated query by EF Core using my example is exactly as the 2nd one

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE [Production].[References] SET [Name] = @p0
  WHERE [Id] = @p1;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

This solves the problem

Comment: How exactly does having 50 columns have an impact on performance? There will be only one `UPDATE` query anyway, regardless if one property is changed or 50.

Comment: It looks bad practice to just update everything, what if my entity has properties like IsDeleted and stuff like that

Comment: What are the generated `UPDATE` queries when you change only one property and when you change 50 properties?

Comment: i updated my post with the sql generated with a short example

Comment: It looks like only the changed property gets updated, which makes sense. So what is the performance problem you are talking about?

Comment: There must be some overhead if it's setting all the columns, specially if omse have index

Comment: Please edit your question to include a detailed description of the performance problems you have. It is a little bit unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. As seen in your generated `UPDATE` queries, Entity Framework update only columns when needed (if they are changed).

Comment: I posted a possible solution for my problem with the intended result i was looking for

Comment: I agree it is bad practise to update the whole record.  If 2 users load the same record.  User1 updates Name, User2 updates address.  User1 saves, User2 then saves. The name which was updated by User1 is reset back to original value by user2 who was only updating address.  Not end of the world for name/address, but could be really bad in certain situations.